# LIMIT clause not working in phonegap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

this javascrip code works fine in phonegap:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {

            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Messages ', [], function(tx, results) {

                    //do something

            }, errorSQL);

}, errorSQL);
```

but if I add LIMIT clause the query does not work

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Messages LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 ', [], function(tx, results) {

                    //do something

        }, errorSQL);
}, errorSQL);
```

the error function show me a message error type undefined

```
function errorSQL(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
}
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: only change the id settings of table when it is created. Simply add integer and auto-increment clause

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages (id integer primary key autoincrement, idm, user, name, type, message, time)'
```